# Initializing an array at return of an ajax request

Tags: angularjs

Trying to learn angular I got the following situation.

My application returns product objects from a complex and slow database using ASP.NET Web Api. Because of the slow speed i wanna page the objects returned from the server. I created a viewmodel containing an array of products, the current page and the last page of the products.

For displaying a paging widget I wanna fill my $scope object with an array of pagenumbers for use with  the ng-repeat directive.

I tried filling an array using a function:

```
(in pseudo)
$scope.pages = function(){
      var pageNumberArray = [];
      pagecounter = 1;     
      while (pagecounter <= maxPage){
          pageNumberArray.push(pageCounter);
          pageCounter++;
      }
};
```

with in my view an ng-repeat using this function:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="pageNr in pages()">{{pageNr}}</li>
</ul>
```

It seems to work for displaying but my developer tools console shows errors which seem legit: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

How can I initialize the $scope array (field) without calling a $scope function from the view.

p.s. the array should reinitialize when an ajax request returns a new page (not all page numbers are shown (5 beneath, 5 above the current page).

Answer (score 0):

I think the two-way binding is disturbed by using a function for your ng-repeat.

I would say $scope.pages should be a variable in your scope. If you later update this variable, your view will be automatically updated by the grace of two-way binding.

So something like this:

in controller:

```
$scope.pages = []
for (var i; i < maxPage; i += 1) {
    $scope.pages.push(i);
}
$http.get(...).success(data){
    // update $scope.pages
}
```

In view:

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages">{{page}}</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. for sure the $scope.pages should be a variable. After the [] I expect a semicolon (used to dot this in C#). So where does the for loop come from. May I call some sort of logic out of nothing? (sorry for being the C# developer that knows to little about javascript).